# Mudblazor MudSelect css customization

Tags: css, blazor, mudblazor

I need to customize the look of the MubBlazor MusSelect component. Basically I want to apply a background to the input and let the label with a transparent background.

original:

[image]

Custom:

[image]

This could be easily achieved by overriding some mudblazor css classes in some global css file (e.g. site.css):

```
.mud-input-control > .mud-input-control-input-container > div.mud-input.mud-input-text {
    background: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

In order to be able to use the custom one in combination with the original mudSelect I added a class to the mudSelect component:

```cs
<MudSelect Class="custom-select" T="string" Label="Coffee" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter">
    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Cappuccino")" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Cafe Latte")" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Espresso")" />
</MudSelect>
```

```
.custom-select .mud-input-text {
    background: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

But I don´t want to add a class every time I need to use my custom look so I decided to implement a component that inherits from mudSelect.

**SelectBox.razor**

```cs
    @inherits MudSelect<T>
    @typeparam T
    
    @namespace Common.Components
    
    @RenderBase()
    
    
    @code {
        public RenderFragment RenderBase() => builder => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
    
        protected override void OnParametersSet()
        {
            base.OnParametersSet();
            Class = $".custom-select {Class}";
        }
    }
```

Now we can use our custom component:

```cs
<SelectBox T="string" Label="Coffee" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter">
    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Cappuccino")" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Cafe Latte")" />
    <MudSelectItem Value="@("Espresso")" />
</SelectBox>
```

The goal from this  solution was to differentiate between MudSelect and my CustomSelect but also css isolation by moving the css to the component.  This solution is working but  I couldn´t move the css rules because css isolation is not working.

Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After reading the [Child component support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#child-component-support) from ASP.NET Core Blazor CSS isolation documentation I realized that my problem was that I was not using a parent element where to apply the scope identifier.

So by adding the div and using the ::deep  pseudo-element in my scoped css. Everything worked

**SelectBox.razor**

```cs
    @inherits MudSelect<T>
        @typeparam T
        
        @namespace Common.Components
        <div>
        @RenderBase()
        </div>
        
        @code {
            public RenderFragment RenderBase() => builder => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
        
            protected override void OnParametersSet()
            {
                base.OnParametersSet();
                Class = $".custom-select {Class}";
            }
        }
```

**SelctBox.razor.css**

```
::deep .mud-input-text {
    background: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

::deep .custom-select input {
    padding-left: 5px !important;
}

::deep .mud-input-control {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```